New tag for the internal image hosting
Now that imgur will soon no longer host our images, the imgur tag would become obsolete.
However, I doubt the new upload process, that would host the images internally in Stack Exchange, would work perfectly and without any bugs, plus people might want to add features to it.
There is already the uploader tag, however it's for the upload process itself, not the hosting of the images or the way they're processed later.
So, I believe it's time for a new tag to replace imgur. Thoughts?

"..., the [tag:imgur] tag would become obsolete" You mean that it will become obsolete, due to imgur not hosting our images anymore? Or is it "would" because the tag's not being burninated?

I'd say obsolete in the sense that there ought to be no new imgur questions, and any new questions would likely be about the redirected version, or someone being very confused.

I think part of it is — it's a very soft launch, and no one knows what it's called.
I'd favour stack-exchange-image-hosting personally. This would distinguish that it's an internal host, what the hosting is, avoid ambiguity, and leave room for future options.
As part of this, I'd also suggest updating the imgur tag to reflect the eventual obsolesce of the tool, and of course a good robust tag wiki.
I'd also wonder if differentiating the current alpha/beta phase from the mature product would have value.

I'm going with this one tomorrow, and will rename the imgur tag to imgur-image-hosting and update it's guidance a bit to mention it is obsolete now

@Tinkeringbell, looks like we settled on [tag:image-uploader] - do we want to update that in the answer here?

@KyleMit it seems to me like [tag:image-uploader] has replaced the [tag:uploader] (mentioned in the question, not discussed in this answer), and [tag:imgur-image-hosting] has replaced [tag:imgur], with the tag for the new hosting place being [tag:stack-exchange-image-hosting], as mentioned in this answer/my comment? I'd just drop a comment that [tag:uploader] got replaced too on the question, and leave it at that.

I just didn't see anything under [tag:stack-exchange-image-hosting] so wasn't sure if it was actually in use

Yep, as far as I can tell both are used, for different parts of the process. If you'd like them to all be the same though, no seperate tags for the hosting and uploader, there's a bit more work to do (probably first discuss it with other users in a new post, write good guidance for the remaining tag if they agree then, and then do the synonyms/merges)

My suggestion:
image-hosting is pretty generic and self explaining itself, however might be seen as referring only to the hosting part, not processing the image for example. Still, the best I can think of.

Maybe for uploading people can use [image-hosting] in conjunction with the aforementioned [uploader] tag, so it can be use for questions about hosting, the uploader, and/or anything in between?

@CaveJohnson yeah, that can work. :)

It seems like this would be good as a synonym: [tag:image-hosting] --> [tag:stack-exchange-image-hosting].

Why not image-processing?
The tag wiki for imgur says

for questions about the official use of Imgur's service to handle image uploads to Stack Exchange

It seems to me like this might be a good tag to help cover questions concerning the processing of images, which might be good to include alongside image-hosting (mentioned by @ShadowWizardLoveZelda) if not a good tag on its own.
